# "Whoever he is", is it polite?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Is it polite to refer to someone we don't know as whoever he is?
For example:

> "Jim" is a professional photographer, whoever he is.

I feel it's a little bit disregarding to the person. It sounds not polite to me.

Comment: Yep, it's not polite.

Comment: In this case, it probably means “whoever he [really] is,” as his genuine identity may be in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is not only a little impolite in this particular case but a little strange.

You've already identified the *name* of the person as well as his *profession*. Therefore, *whoever he his* would typically be out of place.

But having said that, the use of the sarcastic quotation marks (or scare quotes) around Jim's name actually makes the fact that it's an impolite statement almost expected—and perhaps not out of place at all.

Because of the scare quotes, the sentence is starting off sarcastically anyway. An inference can be made that the speaker is suspicious of the person's actual identity; there could be some reason to believe that Jim is just a fake name. And "whoever he is" just reinforces that suspicion.

---

Discounting the scare quotes, we normally only use *whoever* when we know nothing at all, or extremely little, about someone:

> Whoever it was, they stole my car.

But if I know that my car was stolen by the professional photographer Jim, I would not be saying "whoever" in the same sentence.

---

Rather than in a sense of "mystery identification," *whoever* can also be used a general sense:

> Whoever stops the gas leak, they had better do it soon.

Here, it doesn't matter *who* the person is, just that it's *someone*.

---

So, I would never expect to hear the sentence in your question (if the scare quotes weren't there).

A variation, however, is common:

> Jim is a professional photographer, *whatever else* he is.

Here, we know he's a photographer and it's an important piece of information amongst all of the other things that he might also be.